# Make calls on Skype with Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: skype, botframework

I'm working with Microsoft's Bot Development Framework. They've released a [calling API](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/calling/) to handle taking calls, but what I'd really like to do is call a user on Skype (i.e. initiate the call). I don't believe they can do this currently, so if not are there plans to add this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype doesn't offer this functionality at this time. I don't have any information about plans to implement bot calling the user with voice, but I will pass on the request to the Skype bot team.